# UITableViewController overlapping bottom safe area

Tags: swift, uitableview, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I added a Tableview Controller in storyboard, The problem is that it's overlapping the bottom safe area on iPhone X. I also have a view at the bottom which is above the safeAreaLayoutGuide. I tried to use auto layout and anchor it to **view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor**, but this doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. This is what I've tried, with other options but no help.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true  }
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is creating new constraints every time `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is called. Not only does this hurt performance, it actually results in duplicate constraints. It's better to do this once in `viewDidLoad` for example.

Comment: @wvteijlingen, Thanks for your response. I tried that same code in viewDidLoad and it's the same result.

Comment: How do you init the tableView? Please show that code

Comment: You may have conflicting constraints in your storyboard - have you tried editing the constraints of the tableview there? It is probably constraining the tableview to the `TableViewController` bottom anchor.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla, I am using a UITableViewController from storyboard.

Comment: @KaylaGalway, I didn't set any constriant for the UITableViewController in storyboard. Only programmatically what I've shown..

Comment: UITableView is not meant to be constrained in a UITableViewController. It is already constrained to the frame of the view. If you want to add constrains to a tableView the best way is to use a blank UIViewController and hook up a tableView inside of it. Of course you can always override the frame and do some hacky stuff but I wouldn’t recommend doing so.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla, thank you. Seems like that's what I'll have to do.